# TSQL Error converting data type varchar to float. Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssms

I am getting the above error, and it hits on my Insert on line 95:
"INSERT INTO @total"
I added the columns topic_name varchar(100), samplegroup_name varchar (50),  subtopic varchar(50)
from a working query, and that caused the error. None of these columns are Floats, the above types are correct. If I comment out those columns then the query runs fine, so I'm not really sure what to do from here.

Comment: This is not an error, when you aggregate values of rows than contains null values, you receive this **warning**

Comment: Have a look: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=9e3ea36dfa1b6f4356313c4b5e187a29

Comment: So it's not trying to convert varchar to float? Or are you only referring to the second part of the error?

Comment: It is not an error, it's only a warning. You should be able to execute your query.

Comment: As a matter of fact, the "error converting varchar to float" is an actual error. And it is to be expected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an issue with the order of the values you try to insert into `@total`.

Look at the definition of `@total`:

```
DECLARE @total TABLE (
   item_id varchar (30),
   item_dbkey int,
   status varchar (7),
   nT float,
   nY float ,
   sigmaX float,
   sigmaSqX float,
   sigmaY float,
   topic_name varchar(100),
   samplegroup_name varchar (50),
   subtopic varchar(50)
)
```

and now note the insertion:

```
INSERT INTO @total
SELECT 
   Item_id,
   CTR.item_dbkey, 
   TIP.Status,
   tpta.topic_name, -- this tries to go into nT
   ttisg.samplegroup_name, -- this tries to go into nY
   TIP.subtopic, -- this tries to go into sigmaX
   COUNT(CTR.item_dbkey),                                                -- Number of exams which had this item_dbkey
   COUNT(CASE WHEN iop.weightage >= 1 THEN CTR.item_dbkey END) C,       -- How many times was this answered correctly
   SUM  (CTAP.raw_score ) AS totalscore,                                -- Sum of all scores (scaled or raw)
   SUM  (SQUARE( CTAP.raw_score ) ) AS totalscore2,                    -- Sum of the Square of all scores (scaled or raw)
   SUM  (CASE WHEN iop.weightage >= 1 THEN ( CTAP.raw_score ) END ) AS totalscorecorr -- When answered correctly, sum the scores (scaled or raw)
```

`topic_name`, for example, cannot be inserted into `nT` column!

Comment: This is the actual answer, thank you sir. It's always something obvious after writing hundreds of lines of code.

Comment: This is a common "pattern", often the simple errors can not be spotted by the programmer who introduced them, a second pair of eyes can help.